# jqueryUI autocomplete menu show effect

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I spend half of a day trying to apply fade effect for autocomplete drop down menu...
The final result is very uncomfortable for me - look like 'lucky shoot', not real solution.

I used jqueryui default demo for example, and add lines:

```
var acMenu = $("#tags").data().autocomplete.menu.activeMenu;
acMenu._basehide = acMenu.hide;
acMenu.hide = function(){
      this._basehide("fade","slow");
      };
acMenu._baseshow = acMenu.show;
acMenu.show = function(){
      this._baseshow("fade","slow");
      };
```

The whole file looks like (© for www.jqueryui.com):

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });

    var acMenu = $("#tags").data().autocomplete.menu.activeMenu;
    acMenu._basehide = acMenu.hide;
    acMenu.hide = function(){
          this._basehide("fade","slow");
          };
    acMenu._baseshow = acMenu.show;
    acMenu.show = function(){
          this._baseshow("fade","slow");
          }; 

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Can you suggest me better solution ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using HTML5 there you could use CSS Transitions to do the Job.

Add/Remove a class on the open/close events of the Autocomplete Instance:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  open: function () { $('ul.ui-autocomplete').addClass('opened') },
  close: function () { 
    $('ul.ui-autocomplete')
      .removeClass('opened')
      .css('display','block'); 
  },
});
```

Then add following CSS:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
}

.ui-autocomplete.opened {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

​
Though I suppose you could do just the same method with the jQuery UI Fade to class method. **Note:** Will produce weird results when there's more than 1 Autocomplete on a page.

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GEZvA/)

Comment: This will work without needing the extra transitions on the .opened class. Transitions only need to be on the original element.

Comment: I used your solution, it worked well until i found a bug. The bug is in the javascript.When you target ul.ui-autocomplete, then there is no need to target the css. I suggest to edit your answer by dropping the .css property which you are using to display it as a block.
What it does is that the opacity changes to zero but the list of items remain in the window since the display is set to block and can be selected on the mouse click.

Answer (score 3):

What about this? (no CSS needed)

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    open: function () { $('ul.ui-autocomplete').hide().fadeIn() },
    close: function () { $('ul.ui-autocomplete').show().fadeOut() }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, i've created a function that applies with each autocomplete in the project, maybe it can be improved, but it works

```
$(document).on('autocompleteopen', function(event, ui) {
  $(event.target).autocomplete('widget').hide().fadeIn('fast');
}).on('autocompleteclose', function(event, ui) {
  $(event.target).autocomplete('widget').show().fadeOut('fast');
});
```