# jQuery ui 1.10.4 vs 1.9.2 autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I use jquery ui 1.10.4 to implement the autocomplete, and it work fine.
but now i have to use the jquery ui 1.9.2, but the autocomplete will not work.

1.The search result will not display, so I add the open() and close() function to solved it. Reference by [jqueryUI autocomplete menu show effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981438/jqueryui-autocomplete-menu-show-effect)

2.But the select function not working now, it will direct to the other page before. I write a conosle.log in the select function, but it not show.

Have anyone can help me to solve it?

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    enable: true,
    delay: 300,
    open: function () {
        $('ul.ui-autocomplete').addClass('opened');
    },
    close: function () {
        $('ul.ui-autocomplete')
            .removeClass('opened')
            .css('display', 'block');
    },
    source: function (request, response) {
      // get data
    },
    select: function (e, ui) {
        console.log('TEST');
        location.href = "http://domain/Page?id=" + ui.item.data;
    },
    autoFocus: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, just change ui.item.data by ui.item.value. Don't know why your console.log doesn't work. What version of jquery core do you use?

```js
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    enable: true,
    delay: 300,
    open: function () {
        $('ul.ui-autocomplete').addClass('opened');
    },
    close: function () {
        $('ul.ui-autocomplete')
            .removeClass('opened')
            .css('display', 'block');
    },
    source: ['apple','banana','orange'],
    select: function (e, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.value);
    },
    autoFocus: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"/>

<input id="tags" name="tags" type="text"/>
```